# Relative and absolute positioning not working with picture elements

Tags: html, css, image, position, css-position

I'm trying to get the woman-illustration to be over the shadow-illustration as imaged here: https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/faq-accordion-card-XlyjD0Oam
But when I give the shadow-illustration a position of absolute and the woman-illustration a position of relative, it seems like the former is not under the latter (even when I change the width so the two imgs are the same).

```
<section class="faq_img-container">
      <div class="main-images-container">
        <picture class="faq_woman-illustration">
          <source media="(max-width: 1109px )" srcset="./images/illustration-woman-online-mobile.svg">
          <source media="(min-width: 1110px )" srcset="./images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg">
          <img src="./images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg"
            alt="illustration of a woman standing in front of a screen">
        </picture>
        <picture class="faq_shadow-illustration">
          <source media="(max-width: 1109px )" srcset="./images/bg-pattern-mobile.svg">
          <source media="(min-width: 1110px )" srcset="./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg">
          <img src="./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg"
            alt="box shadow">
        </picture>
      </div>

      <img src="./images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" alt="" class="faq_box-illustration">

    </section>
```

(that third image does not matter in this case but I wanted to include the whole section.faq)

```
picture.faq_woman-illustration img {
    width: 23.685rem;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: var(--z-index-secondary);
  }
  
  
picture.faq_shadow-illustration img {
    transform: translate(0, -1rem);
    left: 0;
    width: 23.685rem;
    z-index: var(--z-index-lowest);
    position: absolute;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try for example add top=0/bottom=0 in the selector picture.faq_shadow-illustration img